# Jump to previous slide beamer

Tags: beamer, hyperref

In beamer I want to have a button in a slide that when pressed makes the presentation jump to the previous displayed slide (so labeling the slide does not work).

Is there a way to do this? Thank you.

Comment: Do you need a button? Viewers use to have this option and you can use some key combination (Alt+Left arrow) to do it.

Comment: A presentation by itself is a document.  A document usually does not care how one looks at it, or where one has looked before.  Usually, at least.  On the other hand, your pdf viewer usually records where you have looked at, and thus could have such a button.  Most viewer I know do.

Comment: Yes, I do need that button. But I need it embed on the pdf...

Comment: Do you have navigation buttons in your slide footer? One of these buttons jumps back to the previous slide.

Comment: I do have. But I want to replicate that button on another bigger button

Answer (score 2):

I think that `hyperref` command `\Acrobatmenu{GoBack}{text for GoBack button}` will do it. In fact this is how `beamer` declares this function in its `\insertbackfindforwardnavigationsymbol` from `navigation symbols`.